# Obfuscation of language constructs

Tags: php, xor

I was wondering if it was possible to apply the XOR operator to **eval()** or any language construct at all. Take this for an *instance*:

```
$code = '$result = ' . function. '() { return true; };';
eval($code);
```

Considering I call constructs as variables which is invalid, I have no other way to evaluate '**function**' as a keyword except for **eval()** hence the following will be invalid:

```
$_ = (":"^"_").(')'^'_').(">"^"_").(","^"@"); // --> eval
$_($code);
```

So how could I obfuscate **eval()** (in particular with XOR)?

Comment: So, basically, you want to run `eval` without the word `eval` appearing anywhere in your code?

Comment: Attackers often use `preg_replace` with the `e` flag, which allows one to `eval` code without using the word `eval`. (The `e` flag is deprecated since PHP 5.5 but in no danger of disappearing any time soon.) They might also try writing the code to a temporary file and then `require`ing it.